# In gradle, how to set a directory (recursively) as the output of a task? (to be checked and hashed for UP TO DATE checking)

Tags: android, gradle

In http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html in section '*15.9.2. How does it work?*' the gradle docs say:

*"Before a task is executed for the first time, Gradle takes a snapshot of the inputs. This snapshot contains the set of input files and a hash of the contents of each file. Gradle then executes the task. If the task completes successfully, Gradle takes a snapshot of the outputs. This snapshot contains the set of output files and a hash of the contents of each file. Gradle persists both snapshots for next time the task is executed."*

How can I tell gradle to consider the contents of a directory (recursively!) as the output?
I would like the task to run again if anything in the directory that I specified as output changed.

> File is missing ----> out of date!
>
> Directory is missing ----> out of date!
>
> A new file is in the directory that wasn't there before ----> out of date!
>
> etc.

Any difference to the earlier state should cause the task to be not UP TO DATE.

How can I make gradle behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

If the task is implemented as a class (which is preferred) and you control the implementation, annotate the `File` property that represents the directory path with `@OutputDirectory`. Otherwise, configure the task with `outputs.dir("path/to/dir")`.

Note that Gradle's built-in task classes already carry the appropriate annotations.

Comment: Wrong. Per https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html:

`Note that if a task has an output directory specified, any files added to that directory since the last time it was executed are ignored and will NOT cause the task to be out of date. This is so unrelated tasks may share an output directory without interfering with each other. If this is not the behaviour you want for some reason, consider using TaskOutputs.upToDateWhen(groovy.lang.Closure)`